# Anyone aware of any size/length limitations for PDF/Aspose.PDF?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, aspose

So I'm generating PDF from HTML with the help of Aspose.PDF.

Around 121 pages and 68mb is totally fine, if I add some more html tough when saving the file it just has a size of 0(yes I've made sure it's working and valid html -> pdf code.)

Anyone know of any possible limitations regarding Aspose/PDF or had a similar issue before?

Comment: Did you ask their support? What did they say?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is no limitation for the size when converting a file to PDF using Aspose.Pdf. Share your HTML file which you are trying to convert to PDF. Also, which version and platform are you using (.NET, Java etc.).

In case you are not comfortable sharing the file here, you can post the file in [Aspose.Pdf Support forum](http://goo.gl/5sGqFx) for further testing of your issue.

P.S. I am working as social media developer at Aspose.